# Python Argparse add_mutually_exclusive_group()- Need ether 2 args or just 1 args

Tags: python, arguments

I am using Python's 2.7 argparse. I need it to where the user can enter arguements (-a and -b) OR (-c). But but not (-a and -b) and (-c) together. If (-a and -b) are chosen by the user instead of -c, both of them are required. How could I do this?

```
group_key = member_add.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group_key.add_argument('-a',
                       required=True)

group_key.add_argument('-b',
                         required=True)

group_key.add_argument('-c',
                         required=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The current implementation of add_mutually_exclusive_group() doesn't actually
create mutually exclusive groups. There is a [open bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10984) to address this behavior.

Having said that, you could achieve this using:

(a) [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

Example code :

```
# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='help for subcommand')

# create the parser for the "cmd_1" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('cmd_1', help='help for cmd_1')
parser_a.add_argument('-a', type=str, help='help for a')
parser_a.add_argument('-b', type=str, help='help for b')

# create the parser for the "cmd_2" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('cmd_2', help='help for cmd_2')
parser_b.add_argument('-c', type=str,  help='help for c')
parser.parse_args()
```

(b) Small hack for the simple case like yours :

```
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()

# 1st group
ap.add_argument("-a", dest="value_a",  help="help for a", required=False)
ap.add_argument("-b", dest="value_b",  help="help for b", required=False)

# 2nd group
ap.add_argument("-c",  dest="value_c", help="help for b", required=False)
args = ap.parse_args()

if (args.value_a or args.value_b):
if (args.value_a or args.value_b) and args.value_c:
    print "-a and -b|-c are mutually exclusive ..."
elif not (args.value_a and args.value_b):
    print "both -a and -b are required."
```

Comment: Such a pity, good to hear that I was not going daft. This all falls flat though when you want args with defaults and it becomes much easier to ```import sys;flags=[f.lower() for f in sys.argv[:1]]``` and then weed them out